# Do I need to merge SVN Vendor Branches in sequence?

Tags: svn, merge, vendor-branch

I have used `svn_load_dirs.pl` to create vendor branches and I have the following versions in my vendor branch

- 1.2.0.1/
- 1.2.1.2/
- 1.3.0/
- 1.3.1/
- 1.3.1.1/
- 1.3.2/
- 1.3.2.1/
- 1.3.2.2/
- 1.3.2.3/
- 1.3.2.4/
- current/

If my working copy is at version **1.3.2**, can I go from that version all the way to **1.3.2.4** with one `svn merge` command? Or do I have to do an `svn merge` for every version from 1.3.2 to 1.3.2.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with one `svn merge`.  If there are lots of conflicts between the vendor branches and trunk, it may turn out to be easier to do several smaller merges though.

You can always try the merge with `--dry-run`; if there are messy conflicts then merge each vendor revision separately.